# Consume Web Service, Possible SOAP version mismatch . net framework

Tags: .net, soap, soapui, .net-framework-version

I am getting below error when I try to consume a webservice using .net framework 4.0
Error:
Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.

When I call the web service from soap UI everything works great.
What do I have to do? any ideas?

I am trying to consume a webservice using .net framework 4.0